# Is it possible to test intersection of two circles faster than with squared-distance algorithm?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, optimization

I have this code to calculate whether `this` circle intersections with `another` circle. I want a faster version, is that possible?

```
this.CheckIntersection = function(another){
  var xC = this.x;
  var yC = this.y;
  var GxC = another.x;
  var GyC = another.y;
  var distSq = (xC - GxC) * (xC - GxC) + (yC - GyC) * (yC - GyC);
  return distSq < (this.r + another.r) * (this.r + another.r);
}
```

Comment: Why do you use `this` and `self` interleaved?

Comment: Oh, thanks, I forgot to change "self" to "this" in last-line. (originally this functions executes in callback)

Comment: This is already an O(1) function

Comment: @PaulS.: I've seen some people that turned a backtracking algorithm into an O(1) algorithm, but where they first had to calculate *2^128* values. It is constant, but only in a very "limited" way.

Comment: If I understand you right, you have to compute `2**128 == 3.4e38` values which is far *beyond* computation power available now.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem reads like breaking md5 with rainbow tables... which as we know, is faster if you want to undo more than a few md5s.

Comment: @PaulS.: no it was an optimization problem in the area of constraint programming. Big oh analysis is indeed a very valuable concept, I use it every day. But one has to be careful in over-generalizing conclusions.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko: indeed. The point is they *found* an algorithm, but were unable to test it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well you can try to improve this a little bit as follows:

```
this.CheckIntersection = function(another){
  var dx = this.x-another.x;
  var dy = this.y-another.y;
  dx = dx*dx+dy*dy;
  dy = this.r+another.r;
  return dx < dy*dy;
}
```

This will be a bit faster since you save some subtractions, and you use less variables so the runtime environment will have an easier job with register allocation/caching.

But in terms of time complexity there is not much you can do. So you are limited to peephole optimization like for instance looking for duplicated computation and try to compute them only once.

Comment: If less code was faster, then why not replace the last 3 lines with `return (dx*dx+dy*dy) < Math.pow(self.r + another.r, 2)`. But less code is not necessarily faster.

Comment: @RobG: because `Math.pow` is a generic function with arbitrary power. This will furthermore result in a method call which is quite expensive (call frame on call stack, jump, cache fault,...)

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem—not necessarily, only testing will tell. In any case, the speed difference between hosts is likely far greater than between code versions.

Comment: @RobG: that's true. Mind I never claimed that less (shorter) "code" is per faster. Because one has to know what's behind a method call. A `pow` method runs in *O(log b)* with *b* the power. Of course some compilers can optimize this. Furthermore some compilers can even spot that you calculate the subtraction twice, etc. Nevertheless it is better not to count much on the compiler to do optimizations. So better use a conservative approach and try to provide efficient code.

Comment: Yes, but the assumption that a call to a built–in function is slow [*isn't supported in practice*](http://jsperf.com/circle-intersection/2), though I didn't test many browsers (and the speed difference between browsers is much greater than the speed difference between versions). ;-)

Comment: @RobG: yeah sure. It is for instance possible that JavaScript will specialize a call to `Math.pow(...,2)`. Indeed in many cases the browser itself will have a larger impact ;). Nice work (y)!

Answer (score 1):

If you have many such checks, it might make sense to offload them to the GPU. The GPU should be able to do more of them in parallel, but you pay a bit more because you need to copy data to/from GPU. There's not much to do complexity wise.

[Nvidia's cuda](https://github.com/kashif/node-cuda) is a good starting point, but there are other libraries.

Comment: This is indeed a nice approach. I would add that this is valueable if you want to do processing in *batch*. +1.

Answer (score 1):

If you ask for a faster test, you probably identified a bottleneck there, meaning that you must be using this function intensively.

For a test of a single circle against a single other, there is about nothing that you can reduce. The test essentially takes 3+/2* to compute a squared Euclidean distance and a comparison to a term obtained with 1+/1*. There is nothing you can remove, and the code is so tiny that you probably pay more for the interpreter overhead than for the operations themselves.

Things can become more interesting, and potential gains much higher, if you have to test a moving circle against N fixed circles, or, better, N circles against each other.